# C# Any frameworks allowing me to export data numerous sources? SQL, Oracle, XLS etc

Tags: c#

Are there any 3rd party frameworks that allow me to easily export to SQL, Oracle, XLS etc? I have a C# Windows app that contains a large amount of data in a datagrid that needs to be exported to numerous databases etc.

Thanks
Steven

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's called ODBC.

Comment: I was after something that you can drag on to a form and has all the export options predefined.